# How to deploy Django application to EC2 of AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

**Premise · What you want to realize**

I would like to deploy django application to EC2 of AWS.
The server uses nginx.
I am also trying to do with uWSGI.
The virtual environment is made with virtualenv.
Thank you.

**Problems occurring · Error messages**

The process of nginx, wsgi is running, but localhost can not run the application.
If I hit curl it will get Internal Server Error.

**log**

```
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!! 
chdir() to /opt/app/apolo_api 
your processes number limit is 3896 
your memory page size is 4096 bytes 
detected max file descriptor number: 1024 
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes 
thunder lock: enabled 
uWSGI http bound on :5001 fd 3 
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/uwsgi.sock fd 6 
Python version: 3.5.1 (default, Sep 13 2016, 18:48:37)  [GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] 
Set PythonHome to /opt/app/venv/ 
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x225ace0 
python threads support enabled 
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections 
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds 
mapped 166112 bytes (162 KB) for 2 cores 
* Operational MODE: threaded * 
added /opt/app/apolo_api/api/ to pythonpath. 
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error) 
* no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode * 
* uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode * 
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 22526) 
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 22527, cores: 2) 
* Stats server enabled on /tmp/uwsgi.stats.sock fd: 12 * 
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 22528)
```

Probably

```
* No app loaded. Going in full dynamic mode *
```

It seems that it has stopped starting at the part of.

**What I tried**

Create /etc/init/uwsgi_myproject.conf file

```
Create /etc/init/uwsgi_myproject.conf file
description "uWSGI starter for myproject"

start on (local-filesystems and runlevel [2345]) 
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi /etc/init/myproject.ini
```

Create /etc/init/myproject.ini file

```
[uwsgi] 
chdir=/opt/app/myproject 
module='myproject.wsgi:application' 
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock 
env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings 
master = true 
uid = nginx 
gid = nginx 
http = :5001 
venv = /opt/app/venv/ 
python-path = /opt/app/apolo_api/api/ 
wsgi = app:app 
processes = 1 
threads = 2 
stats = /tmp/uwsgi.stats.sock 
memory-report = true 
thunder-lock = true 
max-requests = 500 
max-requests-delta = 30 
touch-reload=/tmp/.uwsgi_reload
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any specific reason on trying to deploy on ec2 rather than using something like Elastic Beanstalk?